# AJAX load multiple articles with different comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've managed to refresh whole pages or single elements with Ajax. However, i am now trying to update my article-comments on the go.

I have an articles page, which outputs all the articles. Beneath each article, there is a table which outputs the comments belonging to the article, and a form to write a new comment.

How do i refresh each of these tables at the same time?

I've been looking at this, but i can't get it implemented correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //ajax.php is called every second to get view count from server
   var ajaxDelay = 1000;
   var ids = [];
   $('[id^="zone-"]').each( function() {
      ids.push( this.id );
   });
   setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                data: { refresh: 'hits', ids: ids },
                success: function(data) {
                    for (var key in data) {
                        var div = $('#zone-' + key).html( data[key] );
                    }
                }
            });
    }, ajaxDelay);
});
```

[jQuery AJAX live update on multiple elements on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277161/jquery-ajax-live-update-on-multiple-elements-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Please elaborate on the question, what do you mean by refresh? Are you  trying to load content via ajax?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to make it load every 5 seconds or so, if possible just when there's new content